# awk unexpectedly removes dot from string

Tags: awk, csv

I want to add a column (2nd place) in a `.csv` file and I want the values of that column to be strings and to be quoted;

The following command does add the column but without quotes:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$2="2.4.0"; print}' test.csv > output.csv
```

The following approach does incorporate the quotes, but for some reason it removes the last `.` (dot) from the value

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$2="\""2.4.0"\""; print}' test.csv > output.csv
```

so my values end up being "2.40".

How should I go about this?

Comment: If your file have 2 or more columns, you want to insert or replace the second column ?

Comment: just insert a column after the first one

Comment: ok, so to insert, you must use : awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=$1",\"2.4.0\""}1'

Comment: or awk '{sub(",",",\"2.4.0\",")}1'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to have got the quotes wrong. You need to do as below

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$2="\"2.4.0\""; print}' test.csv > output.csv
```

This is explained in the [GNU awk man page - 3.2 Escape Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html#Escape-Sequences)

> Some characters cannot be included literally in string constants `("foo")` or regexp constants (`/foo/`). Instead, they should be represented with escape sequences, which are character sequences beginning with a backslash (`\`). One use of an escape sequence is to include a double-quote character in a string constant. Because a plain double quote ends the string, you must use `\"` to represent an actual double-quote character as a part of the string..

---

As far as the reason I could understand the reason for the behavior, `awk` seems to have interpreted `2.4.0` as a numeric word with the extra quotes from your OP and decides to lose the precision after the first dot.

i.e.

```
$2="\""2.4.0"\""
```

becomes just

```
$2=""2.4.0""
```

which `awk` no longer understands as a string. You can reproduce this behavior by simply doing

```
awk 'BEGIN { print ""2.4.0"" }'
2.40
```

which happens to be the result when you do

```
awk 'BEGIN { print 2.4.0 + 0 }'
```

Comment: @roaima: From what I've know, it seems to have just cancelled out and just resulting in `{ print 2.4.0 }` or `{ print 2.4.0 + 0 }`, i.e. as a non-string constituent. I've tried to search fro relevant docs too, but couldn't

Comment: Another way of conveniently adding quotes that I sometimes use, is to define a variable, e.g.: `awk -v q='"' '... print q "2.4.0" q ...`